# 'Synchronized' on inner object, for ex. gameloop.player1

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I know how monitors work, locking objects, deadlocks etc, but this is unclear for me and I have to be sure, that I'm doing it correctly.

Let's say that I have an object `gameloop`.
Inside that object we have to players: `player1` and `player2`

My `gameloop` renders, reads user's input and modifies `player1` and `player2` in `synchronized` blocks.

I also have a second `Thread`, which listens for packets over the network. 
When player's position packet comes, it has to write it to the player.

And here comes my question:

```
synchronized(gameloop.player2){
    gameloop.player2.setX(packet.receivedX);
    gameloop.player2.setY(packet.receivedY);
}
```

Does above block 'synchronize' only on `player2` object, or locks the whole gameloop (which would be bad in this case)? 
I don't know how to test it and can't find anything related to 'synchronizing on inner objects'.

Thanks!

Comment: The above code synchronizes only on player2 object. But you also mentioned that gameloop` renders...modifies player1 & player2 using synchronized blocks. On which object(s) are you synchronizing in `gameloop`? In case you are not synchronizing on player2 object when modifying player2 state with `gameloop` then you are in a problem.

Comment: Gameloop renders, I mean it gets 'player2' x and y and uses them to draw. It is in a synchronized block: synchronized(player2){{draw(player2.getX(),player2.getY())}}
This is safe, right?

Comment: Yes,that is safe, as you are synchronizing on player2 in the gameloop.

Comment: You can test it using Thread.holdsLock(gameloop.player2) or Thread.holdsLock(gameloop) see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#holdsLock(java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would lock on gameloop.player2, meaning any other synchronized block also trying to lock on gameloop.player2 would have to wait until your posted code is finished. You would want to lock on player2 whenever you need to update player2

Comment: but accessing only 'gameloop' without 'synchronized' is safe, right?

Comment: I don't know what you're doing when accessing gameloop, so I can't say for sure. In general, whenever you're modifying variables or reading from them (unless they're final and are never modified), you should lock on some object which is always locked on whenever accessing/modifying these variables. The object you use to lock on doesn't matter

Comment: For instance I sometimes create objects like "Object somethingLock = new Object();", and lock on that somethingLock whenever reading/modifying "something"